# Given a basis, is there a unique inner product such that that basis is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know there is a unique way to define an inner product such that the basis are orthonormal. Given a basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3,\dots,e_n),$ we can use the Kronecker delta function $(e_j,e_k)=0$ if $j$ is not equal to $k$, and $1$ if $j$ and $k$ are the same. The inner product defined this way is unique. Now if instead of orthonormal, we only required an inner product such that the basis is orthogonal, is the inner product unable to be unique because this requirement isn't strict enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can just scale a given inner product by any positive real number.